# Lookup and return values to duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have two tables exported out of our ERP system. The data is related but one of the tables does not include the customer ID. One table is the customer master list, the other is a list of card numbers assigned to customers. For example:

```
Master list: ID and Name
1 Bill
2 Sam
3 Tim

Other list: Name and Card number
Bill 1234
Bill 1456
Bill 6743
Sam 3333
Tim 5555
Tim 5678
```

I want the customer ID to return next to each of their card number entries. Like:

```
1 Bill 1234
1 Bill 1456
1 Bill 6743
2 Sam 3333
3 Tim 5555
3 Tim 5678
```

I've been trying to do a VLOOKUP and an IF statement with VLOOKUP but I can't get the ID to display when returning a value to multiple entries.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `INDEX` and `MATCH` for this. See my example and replace my german `VERGLEICH` with `MATCH`, `INDEX` should be the same.

[image]